# Use variables only if exists into a array filter express

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I have an endpoint in express with some variables, each of them can be there or not, depending of the variables i have to do a filter function over a array and applie the rules coming fron the req.body.

Is there any way to apply if conditions inside the return of an filter function?

The code is this:

```
test.getModelsFile = async (req, res) => {
 let data = json;
 const SubModel = req.body.SubModel;
 const Years = req.body.Years;
 const Engine = req.body.Years;
 const Make = req.body.Make;

  let result = data.filter((x) => {
   return x.Make == Make(Years) && x.Years == Years && x.Engine == Engine && x.SubModel == SubModel;
  });
result = await deleteRepeatedFromArray(result, "Model");
res.send(result);
};
```

This will only work if those variables came from the req.body, if they are not it will return an error, what can i do?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the variables are not present in the body, then? And `const Engine = req.body.Years;` looks like a typo?

Comment: I dont want to apply that specific filter, if there is no Years variable, i dont want it to be in the filter function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array of the properties you want to look over. Then you can use `Array.prototype.every` to check that, for every property, either:

- It doesn't exist in the `req.body`, or
- It exists, and is equal to the property on the item being iterated over

```
test.getModelsFile = async (req, res) => {
   const properties = ['SubModel', 'Years', 'Engine', 'Make'];
   const result = json.filter(item => properties.every(
      prop => !req.body[prop] || req.body[prop] === item[prop]
   ));
   const payload = await deleteRepeatedFromArray(result, "Model");
   res.send(payload);
};
```

Comment: It is only working with SubModel and Make properties, the others arent, is that normal?

Comment: I assumed your `const Engine = req.body.Years;` is a typo, but you didn't respond to that part of my comment earlier. Is it? Or did you really mean for Engine and Years to contain the same value, from the `.Years` property of the request?

Comment: Yep, it was a typo, sry